# Weird resistor code

Tags: resistors, surface-mount

I have an IDE hard drive that I have been looking at, and I noticed a bunch of network resistors on the PCB that have a **0EE** label on it. As far as I know, this does not comply with the 3-digit, 4-digit, or EIA-96 system. Does anybody know what system these use or the resistance of these resistors? The model number of the hard drive is ST380011A.

[image: r]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is "330", which will be 33 ohms.